# I want to display my results in table format after passing a parameter of id and button click in my library management system

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

This is my entire code to generate reports for a particular student using his/her student id. 
My `SQL` query will show the list of books not yet returned by the student....

While debugging I noticed that if I Manually put any student ID in the code, I can see the results but the button click feature is not working ... somehow the button is not taking any data from my `SQL` query and not executing..

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])==0)
{   
    header('location:index.php');
}
else
{ 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <title>
        Online Library Management System | Report Generation
    </title>
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP CORE STYLE  -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- FONT AWESOME STYLE  -->
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- DATATABLE STYLE  -->
    <link href="assets/js/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- CUSTOM STYLE  -->
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- GOOGLE FONT -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

</head>
<body>
    <!------MENU SECTION START-->
    <?php include('includes/header.php');?>
    <!-- MENU SECTION END-->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
         <div class="container">
             <div class="row pad-botm">
                 <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h4 class="header-line">
                        Employee Reports
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <?php if($_SESSION['error']!="")
                    {?>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" >
                                <strong>
                                    Error :
                                </strong> 
                                <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['error']);?>
                                <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['error']="");?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if($_SESSION['msg']!="")
                    {?>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="alert alert-success" >
                            <strong>
                                Success :
                            </strong> 
                            <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['msg']);?>
                            <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['msg']="");?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>

               <?php if($_SESSION['delmsg']!="")
               {?>
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                       <div class="alert alert-success" >
                           <strong>
                               Success :
                           </strong> 
                           <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['delmsg']);?>
                           <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['delmsg']="");?>
                       </div>
                  </div>
              <?php } ?>

          </div>


      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-1"">
              <div class="panel panel-info">    
                  <div class="panel-body">
                      <form role="form" method="post">

                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label>
                                  CPF NUMBER<span style="color:red;">*</span>
                              </label>
                              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="studentid" id="studentid"  autocomplete="off"  required />

                          </div>

                          <button type="submit" name="report" id="submit" class="btn btn-info">
                              Generate 
                          </button>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <!-- Advanced Tables -->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Issued Documents
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>#</th>
                                        <th>Employee Name</th>
                                        <th>Document Name</th>
                                        <th>Reference Number</th>
                                        <th>Issued Date</th>
                                        <th>STATUS</th>        
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php 

                                    if($query->rowCount() > 0)
                                    {
                                        foreach($results as $result)
                                        {                         

                                            if(isset($_POST['report']))
                                            {

                                                $studentid=strtoupper($_POST['studentid']);
                                                $sql = "SELECT tblstudents.FullName,tblbooks.BookName,tblbooks.ISBNNumber,tblissuedbookdetails.IssuesDate,tblissuedbookdetails.RetrunStatus,tblissuedbookdetails.id as rid from  tblissuedbookdetails join tblstudents on tblstudents.StudentId=tblissuedbookdetails.StudentId join tblbooks on tblbooks.id=tblissuedbookdetails.BookId where tblissuedbookdetails.RetrunStatus is NULL and StudentId=:studentid order by tblissuedbookdetails.id desc";
                                                $query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
                                                $query->execute();
                                                $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

                                    ?>

                                    <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                        <td class="center"><?php echo htmlentities($cnt);?></td>
                                        <td class="center"><?php echo htmlentities($result->FullName);?></td>
                                        <td class="center"><?php echo htmlentities($result->BookName);?></td>
                                        <td class="center"><?php echo htmlentities($result->ISBNNumber);?></td>
                                        <td class="center"><?php echo htmlentities($result->IssuesDate);?></td>
                                        <td class="center">
                                            <?php if($result->RetrunStatus==NULL)
                                            {
                                                echo htmlentities("Not Returned Yet");
                                            } else {
                                                echo htmlentities("Returned");
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="center">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php $cnt=$cnt+1;}}} ?>                                      
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>    
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!--End Advanced Tables -->
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
<!-- CONTENT-WRAPPER SECTION END-->
<?php include('includes/footer.php');?>
<!-- FOOTER SECTION END-->
<!-- JAVASCRIPT FILES PLACED AT THE BOTTOM TO REDUCE THE LOADING TIME  -->
<!-- CORE JQUERY  -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS  -->
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- DATATABLE SCRIPTS  -->
<script src="assets/js/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- CUSTOM SCRIPTS  -->
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: First of all, the button that you have used to generate report does not have any student id of particular student. So you should have separate button for each student row in table with student id.

Comment: Another thing. You've added a placeholder `:studentid` in your SQL query, but you never pass any parameter to it when you executing your query. That that should give you an error.

Comment: How do I do that? @LovepreetSingh

Comment: How do I do that @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Place link to generate report in `foreach` loop along with other rows.

Comment: Here's the manual about PDO and prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: @LovepreetSingh Could you post it as an answer ?

Comment: @LovepreetSingh Cause I did what you asked me to but I still can't get it through...

Comment: Post your updated code.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh Posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to put `studentid` in input field value. So that when form submit, it posted and generate report. Update the following line and check.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="studentid" id="studentid"  autocomplete="off"  required value="<?php echo strtoupper($_POST['studentid']); ?>" />
```